# Error passing value to Java - null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to pass class code through a java communication channel like this:

```
onImageCapture() async {
    try {
      await platform_foto.invokeMethod('onImageCapture', {
        "codigo": widget.cod
      });
    } on Exception catch (e) {}
  }
```

but I get:

> null check operator used on a null value

In the same class, I can display class code normally like this:

```
Text(
"Cód. Aula: " + widget.codigo.toString(),
 style: TextStyle(
 fontSize: 15,
 fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
```

I am stating it this way:

```
class Monitoramento extends StatefulWidget {
  final int cod;
 .
 .
 .
  const Monitoramento(
      {this.cod,.. ..., ...});

  @override
  MonitoramentoState createState() => new MonitoramentoState();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? In one point of the code it works, but in another it doesn't? Should I switch to null security?

I'm using the version: Flutter 2.2.3

I appreciate any comments!

Comment: before using any null operator you should confirm that it is not null by adding an if condition for your variable just to check its null or not if it passes the test condition then only you should proceed to use add null check otherwise it might cause you this problem